# Read data from sql database using datetime picker

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, datagridview, datetimepicker

How to read data from database using datetimepicker value. I have a datetimepicker and a datagridview in my form. I want to get data from Sql databse table with the selected datetimepicker value. I try with this code

```
Private Sub BTNFIND_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNFIND.Click
    getConnect()
    Dim editdate As String
    DTPEDITAT.Value= Format(DTPEDITAT.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy")
    editdate = DTPEDITAT.Value
    MessageBox.Show(editdate)
    Try
        Conn.Open()
        Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,AT_STATUS,AT_REMARK FROM ATTENDANCE WHERE AT_DATE = '" & editdate & "' ORDER BY EMP_NAME ASC"
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, Conn)
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "ATTENDANCE")
        Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("ATTENDANCE")
        Dim row As DataRow
        Dim atstat As String
        For Each row In dt.Rows
            If row("AT_STATUS") = 1 Then
                atstat = "Present"
            ElseIf row("AT_STATUS") = 0 Then
                atstat = "Absent"
            ElseIf row("AT_STATUS") = 0.5 Then
                atstat = "Halfday"
            Else
                atstat = "Error"
            End If
            For x As Integer = 0 To ATCEDITGRID.Rows.Count - 1
                ATCEDITGRID.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value = row("EMP_ID")
                ATCEDITGRID.Rows(x).Cells(3).Value = row("EMP_NAME")
                ATCEDITGRID.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value = atstat
                ATCEDITGRID.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value = row("AT_REMARK")
            Next x
        Next row
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "SQL Error")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "General Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Datagridview not display anything and there is no error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my code like this

```
Private Sub BTNFIND_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNFIND.Click
    ATCEDITGRID.Rows.Clear()
    getConnect()
    Dim editdate As String
    DTPEDITAT.Value = Format(DTPEDITAT.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy")
    editdate = DTPEDITAT.Value
    Try
        Conn.Open()
        Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,AT_STATUS,AT_REMARK FROM ATTENDANCE WHERE AT_DATE = '" & editdate & "' ORDER BY EMP_NAME ASC"
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, Conn)
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "ATTENDANCE")
        Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("ATTENDANCE")
        Dim row As DataRow
        Dim atstat As String
        For Each row In dt.Rows
            If row("AT_STATUS") = 1 Then
                atstat = "Present"
            ElseIf row("AT_STATUS") = 0 Then
                atstat = "Absent"
            ElseIf row("AT_STATUS") = 0.5 Then
                atstat = "Halfday"
            Else
                atstat = "Error"
            End If
            Me.ATCEDITGRID.Rows.Add(row("EMP_ID"), row("EMP_NAME"), atstat, row("AT_REMARK"))
        Next row
        ATCEDITGRID.TopLeftHeaderCell.Value = "Sr.No."
        Me.ATCEDITGRID.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Padding = New Padding(3)
        ATCEDITGRID.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        AddRowHeadersEdit()
        Conn.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "SQL Error")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "General Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Itz working Good....

Answer (score 2):

We see these questions here every day. They stems from the same problem.

**NEVER USE STRING CONCATENATION TO BUILD SQL QUERIES.**

It's a big problem. Of course you have already met the first effect. How to convert strings in an acceptable way to the effective data type? You need to solve parsing problems with embedded quotes, correct representation of dates and decimal numbers for the underlying database system. But the second and more subtle side effect of string concatenation is [SQL Injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) (This is just an instructive link because SQL Injection is a very large topic)

To solve this kind of problems the only accepted way is to use PARAMETERS.
This means that it is the database engine that solves in an efficient way the question, you need a string with parameter placeholders (the @something) and a collection of Parameters with the exact data type for the value of the parameter.

So your code should change in this way

```
Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,AT_STATUS,AT_REMARK " + 
                       "FROM ATTENDANCE WHERE AT_DATE = @editdate " + 
                       "ORDER BY EMP_NAME ASC"
Using con = new SqlConnection("constring_here")
    con.Open()
    Using cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@editdate", DTPEDITAT.Value)
        ' do whatever you want with the command '
        ' like ExecuteReader or use a DataAdapter to fill datasets'
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: +1 but the problem of the OP seems that he wants a simple code.. `:D`

Comment: @spajce I don't think so. Simple it is always preferable, but error free should be a must. And it is a real bad habit to do in that way. When the error strikes you don't want to find yourself with the pants down. And believe me, the error strikes always when you are demoing your app in front of potential customers

Comment: Is your `AT_DATE` column a text field (varchar, nvarchar)? If so, what do you intend to do applying a LIKE statement to a string representing a date? Searching between periods or after a particular date? There is a fundamental flaw here. A date should always be stored in a datetime or smalldatetime column, otherwise this is nearly impossible to apply this kind of logic

Comment: @Steve- This form is just for edit attendance in a particular date.

Comment: If AT_DATE is a DateTime column you cannot use LIKE. If you want only people at the date selected in the DateTimePicker you use `=` and a parameter of type DateTime (the DateTimePicker.Value) as explained in my answer.

Comment: And don't add that % character before and after the parameter placeholder in the sql text command.

Comment: I change datatype of `AT_DATE` from `datetime` to `varchar(50)` and remove `LIKE` from the query. Now there is no error. But the datagridview not display anything...

Answer (score 1):

My **NOT RECOMMENDED** solution:

Remove the parenthesis and `%` characters. Put a space just before the `ORDER` (though it is not the cause of your syntax error).

Fix the select in this way:

```
"SELECT EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,AT_STATUS,AT_REMARK FROM ATTENDANCE WHERE AT_DATE = '" & _
editDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") & _
"' ORDER BY EMP_NAME ASC"
```

---

What *I do recommmend* you is to learn to **use SQL Parameters**.

The query should looks then like this (note the @editDate parameter place-holder inside):

`"SELECT
EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,AT_STATUS,AT_REMARK FROM ATTENDANCE WHERE AT_DATE = @editDate ORDER BY EMP_NAME ASC"`.

Then you need just to add the parameters to the `SqlCommand`. The easiest way is to do that is to use [SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

`yourSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@editDate", editDate)`

A complete sample:

```
    Dim editDate As Date = DTPEDITAT.Value

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING_HERE)
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,AT_STATUS,AT_REMARK FROM ATTENDANCE WHERE AT_DATE = @editDate ORDER BY EMP_NAME ASC"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@editDate", editDate)

            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
            adapter.Fill(ds)

            For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows 
                [do whatever with the result]
            Next

        End Using
        conn.Close()
    End Using
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) about Sql Parameters

> Command objects use parameters to pass values to SQL statements or
>   stored procedures, providing type checking and validation. Unlike
>   command text, parameter input is treated as a literal value, not as
>   executable code. This helps guard against **"SQL injection"** attacks, in
>   which an attacker inserts a command into an SQL statement that
>   compromises security on the server. In addition to the security
>   benefits, parameterized commands provide a convenient method for organizing values passed to a data source.

Comment: `Dim editdate As Date
editdate = DTPEDITAT.Value` aditdate is not from database. Just a DateTimePicker only.

Comment: If your are using this field of the [DateTimePicker.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value(v=vs.80).aspx) Property, its value is already a `DateTime`, and your database column is typed `DateTime` also then forget about date conversions to string and such stuff, just use sql parameters and add the datetime value directly to the parameter.

Comment: +1, actually this answer have a point..  `:D`, i just look for a straight answer

Comment: @Thanzeem You have a complete sample now. Try and let us know

Comment: @Thanzeem, Mr. Steve is already explained the `Parameters.AddWithValue`

Comment: @Thanzeem please consider using db parameters as suggested by everyone. Which is the db-type of the column `AT_DATE`? Is a `DateTime` column or `varchar/nvarchar` column ?

Comment: @LuisQuijada-- AT_DATE is DateTime type.

Comment: Then you cannot use the `LIKE` operator. Make things easier and safer and try with SQL Parameters. You will soon will get used to them and you'll forget about concatenating strings to the SQLs... That's the way, give it a try!

Comment: I change datatype of `AT_DATE` from `datetime` to `varchar(50)` and remove `LIKE` from the query. Now there is no error. But the datagridview not display anything..

Comment: Please, don't try to fight against `SQL Parameters`. If you need a `DateTime` column don't change its type just because you're having problems with the query, fix the query instead in the way I told you from the beginning or use our recommendation and go for SQL params. Did you give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

Try move a one space near at your `"%)` and I corrected the query. Try to figure out.

```
Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,AT_STATUS, " + _
     "AT_REMARK FROM ATTENDANCE " + _ 
     "WHERE Convert(Varchar(10), AT_DATE, 23) = " + _
     "('" & editdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "') ORDER BY EMP_NAME ASC"
```

Comment: Thank you friend. Thank you for your quick replay. But another error `Convertion failed when converting datetime from character string`

Comment: i modified my answer.. just check the correct format of the date

Comment: check my answer.. but beware my friend. because your query is prone of sql-injection :)

Comment: shows `type Date is not a defined system type`. But i change `CAST(AT_DATE AS Date)` to `CAST(AT_DATE AS DateTime)`. Now not showing any error. But not get any data.

Comment: okay, try to change the `CAST(AT_DATE AS DateTime)` to `Convert(Varchar(10), OrderDate, 23)`

Comment: What do you mean by `OrderDate,23`

Comment: wait, it just forgot, i did just copy-paste from my table `:D` the actual is `AT_DATE`

Comment: I guess you want to filter between by `AT_DATE` not `= or equal` by `AT_DATE`. you can follow the other answers since they are use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

this is my code  its working

oldbc.CommandText = "select * from recette where " & ComboBox1.Text & " between #" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "# and #" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "#"