# SQL injection in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-injection

I don't know how to avoid SQL injection, could someone help me with my problem?

Here is my current code:

```
Private Function INSERT() As String
        Dim SQLcon As New SqlConnection
        Dim SQLdr As SqlDataReader
        Try
            SQLcon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=#####;Initial Catalog=OJT;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=####;Password=#####"
            Dim SQLcmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Patients(pIDNo,pLName,pFName,pMI,pSex,pStatus,pTelNo,pDocID,pAddr,pStreet,pBarangay,pCity,pProvince,pLNameKIN,pFNameKIN,pMIKIN,pRelationKIN) VALUES('" & LabelPNumber.Text & "','" & txtLname.Text & "','" & txtFname.Text & "','" & txtMI.Text & "','" & txtPatientSex.Text & "','" & txtPatientSex.Text & "','" & txtPatientTelNo.Text & "','" & txtPatientDoctor.Text & "','" & txtStreetNumber.Text & "','" & txtStreetName.Text & "','" & txtBarangay.Text & "','" & txtCity.Text & "','" & txtProvince.Text & "','" & txtKinLname.Text & "','" & txtKinFname.Text & "','" & txtKinMI.Text & "','" & txtRelationToPatient.Text & "') ", SQLcon)
            SQLcon.Open()
            MsgBox("Patient Added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            SQLdr = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error Occured, Can't Add Patient!" & ex.Message)
        Finally
            SQLcon.Close()
        End Try
        Return "done"
    End Function
```

Comment: Use [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)

Comment: any example of SELECT STATEMENT with parameters sir rene?

Comment: as appointed by other colleagues, use sql-parameters. I wrote a sample today for [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14660347/1203135) that might be of your insterest also.

Comment: also remember to use a good obfuscator, since .net applications che be easily decompiled revealing all the source code and all your passwords to the database. a obfuscator wont solve this problem but makes it a lot more difficult. in any case i wouldnt use .net for a database application that you give to the pubblic.

Comment: You might be interested in this related question on Security.SE  [How can I explain SQL injection without technical jargon?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25684/how-can-i-explain-sql-injection-without-technical-jargon/25710#25710)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically anywhere you're concatenating strings together to create your SQL statement, especially that which comes from user input, is vulnerable.

Instead of doing this use SQL parameters, which can be added to the Parameters property of your SQL command (`SQLcmd` here).

I'll show you an example with one of your parameters - change your SQLCommand text to:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Patients(pIDNo, ...)
VALUES(@pIDNo, ...)
```

Where `@pIDNo` is a "placeholder" in the string for the parameter value, which is sent separately from the command in the [SQLParameters collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb).

Then you can add a parameter with the same name as this "placeholder", and the value (it will derive the type from the value provided for you).

Here's the example from earlier:

```
SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pIDNo", LabelPNumber.Text)
```

Comment: could you give me some example of that codes with SQL parameters, I'm kinda new to this programming field. I have a SQL parameters on my SELECT STATEMENT but I don't know how to do it in INSERT STATEMENT, could you give me one?

Comment: @Danjor I was editing with exactly that when you wrote this - see my edit.

Comment: thanks for the codes, I will apply it to my program, I just want to avoid SQL Injection >.< because I'm aware of what is INJECTOR.