# SQL code works in a new query, but not in the program- exception error: "only constants, expressions or variables are allowed"

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, exception

The code works as it should and inserts into the table when used as a query in SQL Server Management Studio. I'm new to SQL so any help is appreciated, thanks.

SQL Server Management Studio query:

```
INSERT INTO Site(
    Sub_Company_ID, 
    Site_Name, 
    Site_Code, 
    Site_Address_1, 
    Site_Address_2, 
    Site_Address_3, 
    Site_Address_4, 
    Site_Postcode, 
    Site_Email, 
    Site_Username, 
    Site_Password, 
    Site_Order_Budget, 
    Site_Float, 
    Site_Managment_Percentage, 
    Site_Bond_Percentage, 
    Site_Minimum_Fee) 
    VALUES(
    '01', 
    'a', 
    '1', 
    'c', 
    'd', 
    'e', 
    'f', 
    'g', 
    'h', 
    'i', 
    'j', 
    '1',
    '2', 
    '3',
    '4',
    '5')
```

However when used in the actual program I get an exception error for whatever is typed in the text for for site_name. It says only constants, expressions or variables are allowed- I don't have this problem when using the string "a" in my SQL statement though. (This is on one line in the program, I just tried to make it easier to read here).

Program Code:

```
Dim str As String = "INSERT INTO Site(
    Sub_Company_ID, 
    Site_Name, 
    Site_Code, 
    Site_Address_1, 
    Site_Address_2, 
    Site_Address_3, 
    Site_Address_4, 
    Site_Postcode, 
    Site_Email, 
    Site_Username, 
    Site_Password, 
    Site_Order_Budget, 
    Site_Float, 
    Site_Managment_Percentage, 
    Site_Bond_Percentage, 
    Site_Minimum_Fee) 
    VALUES(" 
    & lstSubCompany.SelectedValue & "," 
    & txtSiteName.Text & "," 
    & txtSiteCode.Text & "," 
    & txtAddress1.Text & "," 
    & txtAddress2.Text & "," 
    & txtAddress3.Text & "," 
    & txtAddress4.Text & "," 
    & txtPostcode.Text & "," 
    & txtEmail.Text & ","
    & txtUsername.Text & "," 
    & txtPassword.Text & "," 
    & txtOrderBudget.Text & "," 
    & txtFloat.Text & "," 
    & txtManagmentFee.Text & "," 
    & txtBond.Text & "," 
    & txtMinimumFee.Text & ")"
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: Check the value of SelectedValue by putting a breakpoint.

Comment: Your values need to have single quotes around them!

Comment: Selected value equals 1- which is correct

Answer (score 0):

Surround your values with string delimiters (i.e. `'`) :

```
Dim str As String = "INSERT INTO Site(
    Sub_Company_ID, 
    Site_Name, 
    Site_Code, 
    Site_Address_1, 
    Site_Address_2, 
    Site_Address_3, 
    Site_Address_4, 
    Site_Postcode, 
    Site_Email, 
    Site_Username, 
    Site_Password, 
    Site_Order_Budget, 
    Site_Float, 
    Site_Managment_Percentage, 
    Site_Bond_Percentage, 
    Site_Minimum_Fee) 
    VALUES('" 
    & lstSubCompany.SelectedValue & "','" 
    & txtSiteName.Text & "','" 
    & txtSiteCode.Text & "','" 
    & txtAddress1.Text & "','" 
    & txtAddress2.Text & "','" 
    & txtAddress3.Text & "','" 
    & txtAddress4.Text & "','" 
    & txtPostcode.Text & "','" 
    & txtEmail.Text & "','" 
    & txtUsername.Text & "','" 
    & txtPassword.Text & "','" 
    & txtOrderBudget.Text & "','" 
    & txtFloat.Text & "','" 
    & txtManagmentFee.Text & "','" 
    & txtBond.Text & "','" 
    & txtMinimumFee.Text & "')"
```

But this kind of insert is wide open to SQL injections. Use something like [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead.

And hash your password before storing it.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help I will try this- this is just a test for now the passwords will be secured eventually

Comment: for an example of how to use the SQLCommand with parameters check out this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661027/sql-injection-in-visual-basic-2010

Comment: Although this fixed the initial problem I'm now receiving an error "sql there are more columns in the insert than values specified". However there are 16 columns and 16 values.

Comment: Can't say anything without seeing the variables content. Check that you escape `'` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This code will allow you to avoid sql injection and also allow for you to not worry about appending the correct '' in your update statement. Makes it easier to maintain as well.

```
 Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)

Dim str As String = "INSERT INTO Site(Sub_Company_ID, Site_Name, Site_Code," & _
"Site_Address_1,Site_Address_2, Site_Address_3, Site_Address_4, Site_Postcode," & _
"Site_Email, Site_Username," & _
"Site_Password,Site_Order_Budget,Site_Float, Site_Managment_Percentage," & _
"Site_Bond_Percentage,Site_Minimum_Fee) " & _
"VALUES(@SubCompany,@SiteName,@SiteCode,@Address1,@Address2,@Address3," & _
"@Address4,@Address4,@Postcode,@Email,@Username,@Password,@OrderBudget," & _
"@Float,@Management,@Bond,@MinimumFee)"
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(str, connection)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubCompany", lstSubCompany.SelectedValue)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubCompany", txtSiteName.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubCompany", txtSiteCode.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address1", txtAddress1.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address2", txtAddress2.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address3", txtAddress3.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address4", txtAddress4.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postcode", txtPostcode.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderBudget", txtOrderBudget.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Float", txtFloat.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Management", txtManagmentFee.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bond", txtBond.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MinimumFee", txtMinimumFee.Text)
            Try
                connection.Open()
                Dim rowsAffected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected)

            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
```