# SQL Server Date Conversion from String

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I need to store the date fetch from the ASP.Net text box into a SQL Server 2008 `date` column.

I am getting the following exception message.

> *Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.*

My code is:

```
SqlConnection cn;
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataAdapter da;

int n=4;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cn = new SqlConnection(<Connection String>);
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        try
      {
          string query = "insert into temp values('" + TextBox1.Text  + "')";
          cn.Open();
          cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          cn.Close();
          Response.Write("Record inserted successfully");
     }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Please help ..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Couple of things. 1) Your code is wide open to a SQL injection attack. 2) I guess you are trying to insert into a `DateTime` field but your logic is passing it as a string.

Comment: Again, these question are all the same. String concatenation is BAD. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660255/read-data-from-sql-database-using-datetime-picker/14660601#14660601

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do multiple changes

1. Convert your date as DateTime
2. Pass value as parameter to avoid SQL injection
3. Set the field as DateTime in DB.

Your code would be like that

```
SqlConnection cn;
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataAdapter da;

int n=4;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
cn = new SqlConnection(<Connection String>);
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
      string query = "insert into temp values(@date))";
      cn.Open();
      cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date",Convert.DateTime(TextBox1.Text));
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      cn.Close();
      Response.Write("Record inserted successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
     Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your code to the following (assuming the column in `temp` is actually a `DateTime`):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string query = "insert into temp values(@Value)";
        cn.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
        Response.Write("Record inserted successfully");
 }
catch (Exception ex)
{
     Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
```

}

You should also change your logic to validate that `TextBox1.Text` is actually a valid date.

Comment: @user2017483 What value is in TextBox1.Text at the point you click the button? What data type is the column in `temp`?

Comment: The data type of column in sql server is Date..

And the value in textbox would be 13-05-1990 (dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: @user2017483 It's odd that `DateTime.Parse` failed to handle that date format. As you have found from syed's answer `Convert.ToDateTime` seems to handle that better.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do check if the column datatype is set to datetime
2. Use convert.ToString before inserting into the database